# Google Analytics Android not working

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics to track the PageViews and Events of my App.

```
tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
tracker.setDebug(true);
tracker.startNewSession(getString(R.string.ga_auth), 10, this);
tracker.trackPageView("/test");
```

I'm getting the

```
01-14 12:17:53.697: V/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(24795): HTTP Response Code: 200
```

but in my Analytics Page is nothing - waiting for 3 days now....

Has anyone been facing the same problem?

Best regards

Edit: Just tested v2 Beta of Google Analytics and its working fine... But still interested in how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on this interesting post : 
[Google Analytics – Common Problems and Fixes](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/google-analytics-common-problems-and-fixes/)

Comment: already read the complete post and tried everything - the dispatcher is sending and getting the HTTP OK result so everything with bad keywords etc must be wrong due to getting HTTP OK

Answer (score -1):

You can use easy tracker , It provides wrapper to Google Analytic.
http://code.google.com/p/analytics-api-samples/downloads/list

Comment: link is brocken